# MS SQL Server NTEXT to INT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I transform/convert/cast a column with type [ntext] into a column type [int]? Let's suppose the column name is Client_ID and the table is Client.
I am using MS SQL Server 2014.

I tried with:

```
SELECT
CONVERT (INT, a.CONTRACT_ID)
FROM [dbo].[src_CONTRACT_CONFIGXML] as a
```

The error message I am getting is: "Explicit conversion from data type ntext to int is not allowed."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You first convert it to NVARCHAR and then to INT. As follows:

```
CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), CONTRACT_ID))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
  CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Client_ID)) AS ClientID
FROM Client
```